# How do I repair this pressure-balanced shower valve?

Tags: plumbing, shower, mixing-valve

We have 3-year-old shower with a "pressure-balanced" valve that is suppose to keep us from getting scalded when someone flushes the toilet.  It worked fine for a while, but now temperature control is erratic and the valve makes a "thunk" noise when you turn the control handle quickly.

I hoping that I can:

1. Replace a cartridge or something, so I don't have to..
2. Tear out the the builtin closet behind the valve to replace the whole thing.

You can see some pictures of the valve below.  It's Moen and I think it is "posi-temp" (their pressure-balanced trademark), but I can't find this particular valve online anywhere.  In particular the large flat head "screw" on the right is missing from the valves I see on Moen's website and for sale at various places (Is it maybe an extra output port, I'm not using?).

Further complicating things, the ["manual"](https://www.moen.com/products/M-Pact/M-Pact-Posi-Temp%2526reg%253B-1-2%2522-CC-Connection-including-Pressure-Balancing/2570) Moen provides for other PosiTemp valves is nearly useless for purposes.

So, in summary, my questions are:

1. How do I figure out what valve this is?
2. How do I find useful documentation about this valve?
3. What do I need to do to fix the "thunking" sound and regain control over our water temperature?

thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Moen Customer Support: https://www.moen.com/customer-support 1 800-289-6636 - get them on the phone, it will be more efficient. Assuming you are a normal residential customer, it should be fully under warranty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get a cartridge.

You pull the little horseshoe clip ( you can see the top tab projecting from the cylinder surface ).  Once the horseshoe clip is removed the cartridge can be pulled out.

I replaced some of these cartridges maybe 10 years ago and HD was able to give them to me for free under the moen lifetime warranty.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the assembly is called "M-Pact Moentrol" and seems to be discontinued (perhaps due to the deficiencies you've noticed).

There are specifications on this page with what cartridge to use, etc.

Source: [Moen](https://www.moen.ca/products/3570)

Answer (score -1):

Give Moen a call. They will replace most parts free of charge. They are located in Cleveland Ohio. Great customer service. It might take up to a week to get the needed parts. FYI, most of the other faucet companies have similar warranties.

Comment: Hi Art, downvote is not mine.  But you should tour the help.  Each answer is expected to add something new and meaningful.